Proving that a set is semi algebraic using Hilbert’s basis theorem
I fix $\epsilon>0$ and consider the set
$$
A=\{(a,b+d,-b)\in\mathbb{R}^3 : a\in\mathbb{R}, b\in\mathbb{R}, d\in(0,\epsilon) \}
$$
I want to prove the set is semi-algebraic. My idea is first to write this as
$$
A= \{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3 : x\in\mathbb{R}, y+z=d, d\in(0,\epsilon)\}
$$
From there, I try to make appear polynomial equalities
$$
A=\cup_{d\in(0,\epsilon)}\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3 : P_{d}(x,y,z)=0\}\quad (1)
$$
With $P_{d}(x,y,z) = y+z-d$
However this is not a finite union of polynomial equalities so I am not convinced by this.
Thus, I tried to complete my reasoning but it is more involved. Here is the approach :
Let
$$
I(A)=\{P\in\mathbb{R}[x_1,x_2,x_3] : P(x,y,z)=0, \forall(x,y,z)\in A\}
$$
It is clear that it is an ideal by the Hilbert’s basis theorem it is finitely generated. Denote $(p_1,…,p_n)$ the generating family of $I(A)$.
Denote
$$
A(I) = \{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3 : \sum_{i=1}^{n}p_{i}^{2}(x,y,z) = 0 \}
$$
I will try to prove that $A(I) = A$
By contradiction if $(x,y,z)\in A\cap A(I)^c$ then we have that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}p_{i}^{2}(x,y,z)\neq 0$ but this implies that the $\sum_{i=1}^{n}p_{i}^{2}\notin I(A)$ which is not possible since $I(A)$ is generated by $(p_1,…,p_n)$. So $(x,y,z)\in A(I)$ and $A\subseteq A(I)$.
Now let $(x,y,z)\in A(I)$ and let $P_{\epsilon}$ be as in $(1)$. Notice that $P_{\epsilon}\in I(A)$. We have $\sum_{i=1}^{n}p_{i}^{2}(x,y,z) = 0$ but $\mathbb{R}$ is a real closed field so this implies $p_{1}(x,y,z)=…=p_{n}(x,y,z)=0$ and so $P_{\epsilon}(x,y,z)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}r_ip_{i}(x,y,z)=0$ and since this holds for any $P_{\epsilon}$ we have $(x,y,z)\in A$ and $A(I)\subseteq A$. Thus $A=A(I)$.
I would like to know if is correct to proceed this way and also if you have an easier way to prove this please. Because I have the feeling that my f second approach is not very natural given the simple nature of the problem.
Thank you a lot

The second part of the post using ideal is false.

Semi-algebraic sets can use polynomial inequalities as well: for a polynomial $p$, the set $\{(x_1,\cdots,x_n)\mid p(x_1,\cdots,x_n) > 0\}$ is equivalently described as the projection of the set $\{(x_1,\cdots,x_n,t)\mid p(x_1,\cdots,x_n)t^2 = 1\}$ from $\Bbb R^{n+1}\to\Bbb R^n$ by sending $(x_1,\cdots,x_n,t)\mapsto (x_1,\cdots,x_n)$. So your idea to write $A= \{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3 : x\in\mathbb{R}, y+z=d, d\in(0,\epsilon)\}$ works, since $d\in(0,\epsilon)$ is equivalent to $d>0$ and $d<\epsilon$, and there's no need to deal with the rest of what you've included in the post.

Thank you ! This means that I can write $A$ as the intersection of two sets that are the images by the projections of the semi-algebraic sets ${(x,y,z,d) : P(x,y,z,d)>0}$ and ${(x,y,z,d) : P(x,y,z,d)<\epsilon}$ on the first $3$ coordinates. Also, even if it is no more relevant, is the second part of my post correct according to you ? I am new to this domain and I would like to know if my understanding of the material is not too bad if you are willing to read it of course. Anyway thank you a lot for this explanation !

I am sorry,  forget the question of my previous comment. Just realized the second part of my post is false since $A$  is a union over $d$ and not an intersection, so the set of polynomials vanishing on $A$, and therefore the machinery that follow, is not relevant here !
